# multiple core query using solrnet

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr4

Im basically trying to achieve the following:

```
q=MyField0:ValueA  
AND 
{!join from=OtherID1 to=MainID fromIndex=Index2 v='(MyField1:ValueB)'} 
AND 
{!join from=OtherID2 to=MainID fromIndex=Index3 v='(MyField2:ValueC)'}
```

So I'm basically joining with two other cores. Is there any way to achieve this through SolrNet?

I've had a look at the ExtraParams in QueryOptions but I'm not getting too far.

I can create the seperate joins using a LocalParamsQuery object with a modified serializer but I've no idea as to how to put this all together to achieve the above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try asking on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/4hLDQ5nNu4Y/eJAhEPIhoiAJ

Answer (score 0):

You would just put all that text is as your "q" parameter, which from what I can tell is the first example in the SolrNet documentation.  I've not actually used SolrNet myself.

https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md